# Segmentation fault when the program tries write out the results

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

Greeting,

Somebody can find, why write out these program segmenation fault, when I take in the all inputs?
I don't find where is the problem, or where should be modify my code

And I would like to get the results?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void inMatrix(int n, double **matrix)
{
    int j, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j= 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void inVector(double *vektor, int n)
{
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &vektor[k]);
    }
}

void outVector(double *vektor, int n)
{
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        printf("%.8lf ", vektor[k]);
    }
}

void lup(int n, double **A, double **b, int v)
{
    int *Permutation = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    int i,j;
    int k;
    double *max = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
    int m=0, p=0;
    int tmp=0, tmp2=0;
    int t=0, isSingular=0;
    double largestElement=0.0;
    double *helpVector = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
    double *helpVectorA = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*n);
    double *helpVectorB = (double*) malloc (sizeof(double)*n);


//    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
//    {
//        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
//        {
//            A[i][j]=D[i][j];
//        }
//    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        Permutation[i]=i;

    for(m=0; m<n-1; m++)
    {
        for(i=m; i<n; i++)
        {
            max[i]=fabs(A[i][m]);
        }
        for(i=m; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(max[i]>largestElement)
            {
                largestElement=max[i];
                p=i;
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            helpVectorA[i]=A[m][i];
            helpVectorB[i]=A[p][i];
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            A[m][i]=helpVectorB[i];
            A[p][i]=helpVectorA[i];
        }
        tmp=Permutation[m];
        tmp2=Permutation[p];
        Permutation[m]=tmp2;
        Permutation[p]=tmp;
        if(fabs(A[m][m])>0.00000000000000001)
        {
            for(i=m+1; i<n; i++)
            {
                A[i][m]=A[i][m]/A[m][m];
                for(j=m+1; j<n; j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]=A[i][j]-A[i][m]*A[m][j];
                }
            }
        }
        if(fabs(A[m][m])<0.00000000001)
        {
            printf("szingularis\n");
            isSingular=1;
            break;
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) max[i]=-1;
        largestElement=0.0;
        p=m+1;
    }

    if(isSingular==0)
    {
        if(fabs(A[n-1][n-1])<0.00000000001)
        {
            printf("szingularis\n");
            isSingular=1;
        }
    }
    if(isSingular==0)
    {
        for(k=0; k<v;k++)
        {
             for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            t=Permutation[i];
            helpVector[i]=b[k][t];
        }
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            b[i][k]=helpVector[i];
        }

        for(i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                b[k][i]-=A[i][j]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
        for(i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
            {
                b[k][i]-=A[i][j]*b[k][j];
            }
            b[k][i]=b[k][i]/A[i][i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%.8lf ", b[k][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

 }

}

int main()
    {
        int k, v,n;
        int j;
        double **A;
        double **C;

        // read dimension of matrix and value
        scanf("%d", &n);
        //matrix
        A = (double **) calloc(n, sizeof ( double*));
        // matrix to store the vectors
        C = (double **) calloc(n, sizeof(double *));

        while(n!=0)
        {
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            A[k] = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof ( double));
        }
            inMatrix(n, A);

            scanf("%d", &v);
            for(k=0;k<v;k++)
            {
                C[k] = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof ( double));
            }

            for(k=0; k<v;k++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    scanf("%lf", &C[k][j]);
                }
            }
            //print out result
            for(k=0;k<v;k++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<v;j++)
                {
                    lup(n,A,C,v);
                }
            }

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [It might help you find the problem if you temporarily put in some `printf`s saying "got to here" and things like that, so you can work out *where* the segfault actually happens]

Comment: So sorry, but I don't understand what do you want to say me

Comment: [When something like a segmentation fault happens in a program, in order to work out where the problem is, it can be helpful to add some things like `printf("I just finished the for loop\n")` to help with debugging, and then remove them afterwards] [edit: or as suggested below you could use a debugger]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function lup, at line 157 (in the second "if(isSingular==0)" block) you wrote

```
printf("%.8lf ", b[k][i]);
```

this line is written in a for-loop iterating on i, while k has a leftover value from the last loop. The break condition of that loop was that k = v (the size of C, A.K.A "b" from the line of code above).

So, basically, you wrote:

```
printf("%.8lf", b[MaxIndexOfB+1][i];
```

And that's probably the stinker you're looking for.

Two notes. First, I've been .Net man for too long, so I might be missing something completely trivial here, In that case, sorry.
Second, when you want people to read your code (like when posting it for help), it's imperative to use more meaningful names, or something to improve code readability, but if you're not going to do this, at least avoid confusing stuff like passing variable named "C" into parameter named "b" if it's avoidable.

Comment: P.S. I don't know if it's intentional, but you're note freeing your allocated memory. Just and FYI

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, you have

```
        /* ... */
        C = (double **) calloc(n, sizeof(double *));
```

`n` elements

```
        while(n!=0)
        {
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            A[k] = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof ( double));
        }
            inMatrix(n, A);

            scanf("%d", &v);
            for(k=0;k<v;k++)
```

`v`? Where did it come from? Do you perhaps mean `n`
Remember `C` was allocated space for `n` elements, even before `v` was set.

```
            {
                C[k] = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof ( double));
            }
            /* ... */
```

Your indentation and use of whitespace could improve a bit too.

Comment: Afther the matrix values

take in the `v` and v is the numbers of arrays (or numbers of vectors)

Comment: If `v` and `n` are different, you either waste memory (when `v` < `n`) or try to write outside the range for `C` (when `v` > `n`)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [tutorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html). It teaches you how to find segfaults using GDB.